# sqlite3 in Node.js does not return the lastID from INSERT callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite

```
db.run("INSERT INTO test VALUES (?)", [testVal], function(err) {
      console.log(err);
      console.log(this.lastId);
      console.log(this);
})
```

err - return null,
this.lastID - return undefined,
this - return Window object

How do I get the last insert identifier?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually you have to use the lastID (capital D).

```
db.run("INSERT INTO foo ...", function(err) {
    // err is null if insertion was successful
    console.warn("inserted id:", this.**lastID**);
});
```

Source: https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3/issues/206