# How to get data from INSERT...RETURNING * in node.js sqlite3

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite, sql-returning

I want to get the row id immediately after creating a new record in a table, I've seen that you can use sql along the lines of

```
INSERT INTO table(value) VALUES (?) RETURNING *
```

to do that but I don't know how to get the data out of the statement afterwards.

So far I've tried

```
sql = ("INSERT INTO table(value) VALUES (?) RETURNING *");
        db.run(sql, [value]), (err, row) => {
          if (err) return console.error(err.message)
          value = row.value
          console.log("value id is:",value)
        }
```

but that doesn't work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The row parameter in the callback function can only be accessed in DELETE and UPDATE statements, is called changes and is an Array. Use `this`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can access the `this.lastID` in the callback when no errors occurs. Like discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39574938/sqlite3-in-node-js-does-not-return-the-lastid-from-insert-callback).

Pay attention to your code, has some typos.
See the documentation [SQLite run](https://github.com/TryGhost/node-sqlite3/wiki/API#runsql--param---callback). Is all there.

```js
db.run(`INSERT INTO table(name) VALUES(?)`, ['value'], function(err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err.message);
    }
    // get the last insert id
    console.log(`A row has been inserted with rowid ${this.lastID}`);
});
```

Last but not least, don't use arrow function in the callback. Like said in the doc too.